# How to access my newly setup MySQL database (getting "Domain is currently unable to handle this request.")

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, windows-server-2012, host

I just set up a new MySQL database with the MySQL workbench & created a user for it with all necessary privileges. I am using this database for use with my php code. But I can't seem to connect to it on my live server (pages are hosted on windows server 2012). Everything works fine in my local environment with xampp and the new MySQL database is exactly the same as the xampp one. I think I am maybe using the wrong host name or something. As host name I copied the name that is displayed after "Host:" when you click on Server Status in MySQL workbench. The database name, user & password should all be correct. But when my code tries to access the db I get a "The domain page isn’t working. Domain is currently unable to handle this request."

Comment: Please add more details to the question like exact queries you fire, logging output and the concerning configuration parts and settings. Questions on SO must be reproducable and clear. "Why is XY not working?" is hard to answer precisely.

Comment: I have never before had to setup a db like this myself, I always could just find & copy the connection info via a cpanel interface and then paste that into my db_config file.
The db I had in phpmyadmin (xampp) I simply recreated in MySQL workbench. I copied the host information from the info you get in server status. That's all I did. I think maybe I forgot some essential steps or should that be all there is to it? (This is all completely new to me sorry)

Comment: How we can tell if you missed some steps when you don't show exactly which steps you have taken + your current configuration? If you don't know where the configuration is, do some basic research on google.

Comment: But the steps I've described are effectively all the steps I have taken. And the configuration is the "my.ini" file? Do I need to paste the entire thing somewhere? Because it is quite large

Comment: I just found out that the MySQL57 Service is stopped and when I try to start it I get "Windows could not start the MySQL57 service on Local Computer. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly". I imagine this has very much to do with the issues that I'm having

Comment: Event viewer tells me these errors: "Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory", "Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306?", "Aborting". And when checking 'netstat -a | find "3306"'  I get "listening", a bunch of "established" & another "listening". Don't know what that all means though

Comment: Maybe you started a standalone mysqld and try to start a daemon one too, only one server can listen on a port.

Answer (score 0):

You either have no network connection to the server at all or it is blocked due to firewall or routing misconfiguration.

If you do have network access in general, you might forgot to

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or you have not enabled networking over TCP, the default is to listen only to localhost (on unix systems via unix sockets, on microsoft I guess it's simply TCP).

Read about the following configuration parameter which will solve your networking issue:

```
bind-address
```

If you have a very old MySQL server version, the parameter is `enable-networking` but it shouldn't be the case anymore.